# Typeahead.js v0.10.0 - On suggestions rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I have just updated to the new version of typeahead (v0.10.0) and so far I am really impressed.

However, I find no way to track the event when suggestions is rendered. Previously I did this:

```
myTypeahead = typeahead({.....});

myTypeahead.data('ttView').dropdownView.on('suggestionsRendered', function() {
    // Suggestions is now rendered
});
```

But this now fails saying:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dropdownView' of undefined`

Do you have any idea? None of the custom events described here: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events can solve the issue.

Comment: Can't you use the "typeahead:opened" event instead?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Because it will only trigger once, and when new results append, I need to manipulate some divs with ajax results.

Comment: See my response on the associated GitHub issue: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/644#issuecomment-34111127

Answer (score 0):

In the typeahead.js file I added a custom event that fires when the menu is opened.

In the following method I added the last line of code defining the event:

```
_updateHint: function updateHint() {
    var datum, inputValue, query, escapedQuery, frontMatchRegEx, match;
    datum = this.dropdown.getDatumForTopSuggestion();
    if (datum && this.dropdown.isVisible() && !this.input.hasOverflow()) {
        inputValue = this.input.getInputValue();
        query = Input.normalizeQuery(inputValue);
        escapedQuery = _.escapeRegExChars(query);
        frontMatchRegEx = new RegExp("^(?:" + escapedQuery + ")(.*$)", "i");
        match = frontMatchRegEx.exec(datum.value);
        this.input.setHintValue(inputValue + (match ? match[1] : ""));

        //custom event fired when menu opens
        //to use: .on('typeahead:rendered', function($e, datum) {...}
        this.eventBus.trigger('rendered', datum.raw, datum.datasetName);

    }
},
```

I know it's a no-no to modify source code, but when in Rome...